# Docker Compose couldn't find a package.json file in "/app"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my project struture

```
.
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── README.md
    ├── build
    ├── package.json
    ├── yarn.lock
    └── ...
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
RUN yarn install --no-lockfile

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

If i build container using docker, it works fine

But `docker-compose up --build` always returns

```
Attaching to book-marketplace_frontend_1
frontend_1  | yarn run v1.22.15
frontend_1  | error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/app"
frontend_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
book-marketplace_frontend_1 exited with code 1
```

it's weird that docker-compose can still run yarn install ( which needs package.json) but can not locate it later. Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are already in workdir `app` as you earlier defined as `WORKDIR`. So change the line to:

`COPY ./package.json /package.json`

Answer (score 2):

Your `volumes:` block is replacing the `/app` directory in the container with something totally different.  (You're using a `frontend` subdirectory as the build context, but then bind-mounting `.` over `/app`; if you `docker-compose run frontend ls` you'll see a `frontend` subdirectory and not your application.)

You can resolve this by deleting the `volumes:` block.  Your container will run the code that's built into the image, and not something else.  A minimal functional Compose setup can look like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can change the line in docker-compose.yml, works for me

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

to

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/app
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days on this issue, you need to add `working_dir` in the docker-compose file as well along with specifying `WORKDIR` in dockerfile

```
  api:
    container_name: my_app
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
```

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
```